# ssh -v -p 222 and other ssh suffix comands are not recognized in terminal

Tags: kali-linux, opensuse, openssh

Background:

I have openSUSE Tumbleweed running on a local server (an old re-purposed HP desktop) and I am going to install LAMP and wordpress on it.  I want to administrate the server remotely so I do not have to have a workstation set up for it.  I also want to try out some penetration testing on the server, and I have a perfect little Toshiba Portege 830 COREi5 with Kali installed on it so that I can search for vulnerabilities in my server.  I figure it will be like playing chess against myself.

Ideally I would like to use the same Portege to administrate the server - however this is where I ran into difficulties connecting from the client to the server, so i tried running recommended debugging commands I have seen on many websites (for example: http://www.snailbook.com/faq/general-debugging.auto.html).

SSH suffix commands do not even seem to be acknowledged by the Kali terminal.  I run the same and other commands in openssh-server installed on the openSUSE server, but no commands are recognized by the openssh-client installed on the Kali notebook.

All of the following:

```
root@kali:~# ssh -v -p 222
root@kali:~# ssh -p 222
root@kali:~# ssh
```

return only a usage printout:

```
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file]
           [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec]
           [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
           [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
           [user@]hostname [command]
```

The `ssh` server is running:

```
root@kali:~# service ssh status
● sshd.service - OpenSSH Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-05-01 03:45:55 BST; 24min ago
 Main PID: 7637 (sshd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
           └─7637 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Why are these commands not working?

Comment: kali is not the best distribution for begginers.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I have been told that Kali is not good for beginners before and i appreciate the time you took to leave this comment.  I have used Ubuntu before, but I really want to push myself to use the terminal as much as possible - after doing a lot of research into what I wanted to do, I concluded that text only openSUSE server with Kali notebook for penetration testing would be a great challenge.  But maybe I should have a second Ubuntu notebook to administrate the server...  What do you think?

Comment: VM or 2nd notebook, not bad idea overall. i have a travel laptop with freebsd

Comment: Kali isn't the easiest distribution to start out with, but it is just debian with a gnome desktop and some pre-installed software (and a much cooler logo, in my opinion).

Comment: Yes, certainly a cooler logo and that is actually what got my attention as well as the possibility for penetration testing.  I assumed that the terminal commands would be the same across all distributions of linux, so I thought Kali would be fine as long as I focused on using the terminal - I quickly discovered I was wrong (for example: 'ifconfig in Kali is 'ip a' in openSUSE).  Actually, I am finding Kali easier to learn than openSUSE since openSUSE commands are sometimes change with new dist-upgrades (in Tumbleweed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ssh -v -p 222` and `ssh -p 222` should return an error on their own. You need to specify a host to connect to, either by ip or by hostname (either qualified DNS name or something specified in `/etc/hosts`). For example, by IP:

```
ssh -v -p 222 192.168.0.3
```

You need to use the IP address of the openSUSE server.

Comment: Oh, it's so simple!  Look how poorly it is explained in steps 1 & 2 of this guide:  https://sfxpt.wordpress.com/2011/03/05/troubleshooting-sshd-server-configuration-2/

Comment: Ok, I get 3 lines of debug1 and then the connection times out.  I suppose I know what I am doing tomorrow then...

Comment: @Matthew make sure you can ping the server from the client.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, it pings fine.  I run the -v -p 222 and I get 4 lines of debug report.  Line 2 tells me '.../ssh_config line 19: Applying options for * ' 
Do you think this means the problem is in line 19 of ssh_config? I have not had time to look this up, I am just trying to use your knowledge right now.
EDIT: ssh_config line 19 says Host *.  Line 20 is ForwarAgent that I have set to YES.

Comment: The lines of debugging are from the `-v` option. You could always try commenting out the `ForwardAgent` line and see if that works, but you really shouldn't have to change much on the client side. The problem is usually on the server side. Try this to see if the port is open: `nmap -p 192.168.x.x`. If it isn't you probably have to open a firewall port.

Comment: Yes, the problem is definitely with the server.  From the server I run 'ssh -v -p 222 127.0.0.1' and I get 'connection refused'.  Same response for 'ssh -v -p 222 user@127.0.0.1'